# Got The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. while json call

Tags: java, json

Here is my impl class :

```
@Path("/initiatePayment1")
public class InitiatePaymentImpl {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public InitiatePaymentResponse initiatePayment(InitiatePaymentReq req){

        logger.debug("Inside the initiatePayment in gateway.");
        logger.debug("Initiate Request Object is : " + req.toString());

        InitiatePaymentResponse res = new InitiatePaymentResponse();

        res.setResponseCode("E0000");
        res.setResponseString("Well Done..");

        return res;
    }
}
```

Below are my Two pojo class:

```
package com.empays.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public class InitiatePaymentReq {

    public InitiatePaymentReq() {

    }

    public InitiatePaymentReq(String senderMobileNo) {
        super();
        this.senderMobileNo = senderMobileNo;
    }


    private String senderMobileNo=null;

    public String getSenderMobileNo() {
        return senderMobileNo;
    }
    public void setSenderMobileNo(String senderMobileNo) {
        this.senderMobileNo = senderMobileNo;
    }

    */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "senderMobileNo=" +senderMobileNo;
    }
}
```

Other POJO calss :

```
package com.empays.dto;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class InitiatePaymentResponse {

    public InitiatePaymentResponse() {

    }

    public InitiatePaymentResponse(String responseCode, String responseString) {
        super();
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
        this.responseString = responseString;
    }

    private String responseCode;
    private String responseString;

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }
    public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }
    public String getResponseString() {
        return responseString;
    }
    public void setResponseString(String responseString) {
        this.responseString = responseString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "responseCode=" + responseCode + ", responseString=" + responseString;
    }
}
```

And from the httprequester ,i am calling the class :

http://localhost:8080/Test/initiatePayment1

Contenttype = application/json

and parameter `{"senderMobileNo":"9820175762"}`

After invoking it gives the :

type Status report

message Bad Request

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: were u able to get message "the initiatePayment in gateway." ?

Comment: _from the httprequester_ What requester ? I always see content-type with a `-`, so if it is your input, this migh be a syntax error in the request itself (seems to be the error message)

Comment: i used the Mozilla httprequester  and select the Contenttype = application/json  and the inputparamter is : {"senderMobileNo":"9820175762"}

Comment: Don't know this plugin but on chrome, with POSTMAN, I use `content-type=application/json` and for the parameter, you need to set the x-form to use POST parameter. (and set the request as a POST)

Comment: tried with the postman, and its giving me the <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u>